# Почему переменная не воспринимается как переменная?

Tags: php, html

Есть сайт, где при заявке на регистрацию на почту отсылается проверочное письмо со ссылкой типа `approve.php?order_id=&email=`.

Возникла необходимость сделать редактируемым текст письма. Для этого создал запись в БД, в которой хранится полный текст письма.

Отправка письма:

```
$mailSMTP = new SendMailSmtpClass($email_from, $email_password, $smtp_host, $email_from_name, $smtp_port);
$entry_mail_result = $mailSMTP->send($email, $approve_theme, $approve_message, $headers);
```

`$approve_message` получаю из базы данных:

```
<html>
 <a href=http://***/approve.php?id=$order_id&e=$email>Подтвердите</a>...
</html>
```

В письме содержатся две переменные `$order_id` и `$email`. Обе инициализируются в php-файле перед отправкой письма (самый первый блок с кодом).

Но в теле письма вместо `$order_id` и `$email` не подставляются эти значения. Прошу подсказать, в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка (?) в том, что из БД приходит просто текстовая строка. Не важно, что в ней что-то похожее на переменные в PHP – как код она не анализируется.

**Как вариант**, можно использовать [форматы](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php). В базе пусть хранится макет письма, где в нужных местах стоят `%s` для вставки туда текстовых значений и `%d` для вставки только чисел. Например,

```
<html>
 <a href=http://***/approve.php?id=%d&e=%s>Подтвердите</a>...
</html>
```

Тогда функцией [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php) туда можно подставить нужные значения:

```
sprintf( $template_from_DB, $order_id, $email)
// возвращает строку, где всё подставлено – можно отправлять.
```

**Ещё вариант**, как делают профессиональные почтовые сервисы, напр. MailChimp. Имеет смысл, когда подставляемых полей становится больше. В тексте / коде письма ставятся свои особенные теги, напр. у вас это могли бы быть `%ORDER_ID%` и `%EMAIL%`:

```
<html>
 <a href=http://***/approve.php?id=%ORDER_ID%&e=%EMAIL%>Подтвердите</a>...
</html>
```

После идёт просто замена всех таких подстрок на нужные значения:

```
$approve_message = $tmpl; // $tmpl - прочитанный из базы макет письма 
$approve_message = str_replace( '%ORDER_ID%', $order_id, $approve_message);
$approve_message = str_replace( '%EMAIL%', $email, $approve_message);
// теперь можно отправлять $approve_message
```

Answer (score 0):

Тело письма формируется $mailSMTP->send, в этом методе $order_id и $email не определены, поэтому и пустота.